# Sending packets meant for an address on 127.0.0.1/8 to the network on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu

I want to test how network infrastructure reacts to non-compliant packets. One of the tests I'm curious about is how network infrastructure reacts when it receives a packet meant for `127.0.0.1/8` from another host.

In order to do this, I would have to make Ubuntu forward packets for an address on this subnet to the network gateway but I am not sure how to do this. To be clear, I'm not looking to send all packets to the `127.0.0.1/8` subnet to the gateway but a particular non-`127.0.0.1` and non-`127.0.0.53` IP as not to break anything.

I have thought of "mapping" an address on that subnet to the gateway IP as per https://serverfault.com/q/692415 but that changes the destination header for the packet before it leaves the host.

Is there any way to do what I'm looking for in Ubuntu? Will modifications to the kernel be required? Alternatively, is this easier to do on a different OS?

Comment: 127.0.0.x/8 - is reserved for loopback. it will not exit the localhost.

Comment: @Zina Surely there is a way to do this though? I'm willing to accept answers which involve applying a kernel patch or something along those lines. Though to be honest, I thought it might be doable simply by setting a custom route or something like that.

Comment: even if you are able to do it, it will not be something happening in a network. se the RFC. [check this answer too](https://serverfault.com/questions/839461/is-127-0-0-1-a-routable-ip-address#:~:text=127.0.,ordinarily%20implemented%20using%20only%20127.0.)

Comment: @Zina Thanks for the link. The comment on the accepted answer was probably the most helpful - `any router seeing an address in that range on the network is supposed to drop the packets that have such an address`. I guess I know the outcome now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might be giving you enough rope to hang yourself. The sysconfig parameter [`route_localnet`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt?h=v5.4#n1220) controls the routing restriction of 127.0.0.0/8, and should be used only for some specific settings probably involving NAT or load-balancing.

> `route_localnet` - BOOLEAN
>
> Do not consider loopback addresses as martian source or destination
> while routing. This enables the use of 127/8 for local routing
> purposes. default FALSE

Eg: for a system with 192.0.2.2/24 set on *eth0* and trying to reach 192.0.2.3 with source 127.0.0.44, the routing stack forbids it by default:

```
# ip route get from 127.0.0.44 192.0.2.3
RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument
```

once set:

```
# sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.eth0.route_localnet=1
net.ipv4.conf.eth0.route_localnet = 1
# ip route get from 127.0.0.44 192.0.2.3
192.0.2.3 from 127.0.0.44 dev eth0 uid 0
    cache 

$ echo test | socat udp:192.0.2.3:4444,bind=127.0.0.44 -
```

The ARP request should still be done by 192.0.2.2, but expect troubles anyway (unless you put the same setting on the other side).

To have a real routing working, you still need to set an explicit route on both sides, because there are still local routes making the system consider all of 127.0.0.0/8 to belong to itself:

On the other system 192.0.2.3 (say also Linux), the route would be ignored since martian, so loosen this too:

```
# sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.eth0.route_localnet=1
```

but still:

```
# ip route get from 127.0.0.44 iif eth0 192.0.2.3
RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument
```

because of the local route.

So in addition, on that other (192.0.2.3) system add:

```
# ip route add 127.0.0.44/32 dev eth0
```

which gives:

```
# ip route get from 127.0.0.44 iif eth0 192.0.2.3
local 192.0.2.3 from 127.0.0.44 dev lo 
    cache <local> iif eth0
```

Now it will be able to receive and send back packets with 127.0.0.44

If you want *both* systems to use an address from 127.0.0.0/8, same kind of setting should be used on original system. Of course they should use a different IP address.

Comment: OP asked how the network infrastructure will react, your answer looks like in-host changes

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, this will essentially make my machine believe that 127.0.0.1 is not localhost, and it will send a packet with that dst address to the network? If so, that is indeed what I'm looking for.

Comment: Ok addressed both sending and receiving on Linux, using 127.0.0.44 (as per OP: not 127.0.0.1 nor 127.0.0.53)

Comment: And before: the system would still consider 127.0.0.1 local, like any other system. Accepting receiving from remote an IP address assigned locally is something else that still wouldn't work, not just with 127.0.0.1 but for any IP address.